# IOS, NotificationQueue call wrapped in DisplaceQueue.global does not fire

Tags: ios, grand-central-dispatch

I am trying to have my notification targets invoke in the background thread.  The documentation asserts the targets will be invoked on the tread where the notification was enqueued.

If I wrap the enqueuing inside the DispatchQueue that runs in the background then the target is never invoked.  If I remove the DispatchQueue then the targets are invoked, on the main thread of course.

```
for aLocation in locations {
            // add it to the queue
            DispatchQueue.global(qos: DispatchQoS.QoSClass.background).async {
                let notify = Notification(name: MyLocationManager.queueName(), object:aLocation)
                NotificationQueue.default.enqueue(notify,
                                      postingStyle: NotificationQueue.PostingStyle.asap,
                                      coalesceMask:NotificationQueue.NotificationCoalescing(rawValue: 0),
                                      forModes: nil)
             }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The short answer would be: `NotificationQueue`s need a `run loop`

---

**The long version:**

> *The documentation asserts the targets will be invoked on the tread where the notification was enqueued.*

This is not entirely true. The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Notifications/Articles/Threading.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001289-CEGJFDFG) asserts this fact only for `Notification Center`s but not for `NotificationQueue`s

Here's what the [NotificationQueue documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/notificationqueue) has to say about it:

> Whereas a notification center distributes notifications when posted, notifications placed into the queue can be delayed **until the end of the current pass through the run loop or until the run loop is idle**.

Then you have the `enqueue` function's 4th parameter:

> **modes:**
>   The list of modes the notification may be posted in. The notification queue will only post the notification to its notification center if the run loop is in one of the modes provided in the array. **May be nil, in which case it defaults to NSDefaultRunLoopMode**.

Combine all this with the fact that `GCD` wont create a run loop on its global concurrent queues, *unless somebody explicitly runs one on them*, then we have this behaviour where the notification queue does not fire.